# Specify time period in domain computed field (odoo 10)

Tags: python, odoo, computed-field

How can I specify a date in the domain of a computed field:

```
for record in self:
last_confirmed_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(
    [('partner_id', '=', record.name),('date_order','&gt;=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))],
    order='date_order desc',
    limit=1000
)
sum = 0
for x in last_confirmed_order:
  sum = sum + x.amount_total
  record['x_last_order_sum'] = sum
```

Gives an error
[image]

Thx for the advice I adjusted my code to

```
for record in self:
    today=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    last_confirmed_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(
    [('partner_id', '=', record.name),('date_order','=',today)],
    order='date_order desc',
    limit=1000
)
record['x_last_order'] = last_confirmed_order.date_order

for x in last_confirmed_order:
 sum = sum + x.amount_total
 record['x_last_order_sum'] = sum
```

I get no error but the value stays zero. While I do have orders for that customer today. Do I have to convert date_order to same format as Y M D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the domain filter operator is the problem

Try using '>=' instead of ">="